# FB Graph API saying Open Graph type not set to the right object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I went to post 8 custom objects/actions so that I can submit a new "collection" for approval. FB just launched this feature a few days ago. I guess it accompanies their new graph layout that will be released soon.

In the API explorer, I tried posting the following URL

```
/me/sportannica:predict?victory=http://www.sportannica.com/predictions/90/predictions_post
```

Upon trying to post this, I'm greeted with a message that says the following:

```
"message": "(#3502) Object at URL http://www.sportannica.com/predictions/90/predictions_post has og:type of 'website'. The property 'victory' requires an object of og:type 'sportannica:victory'. "
```

That warning message seems to be erroneous. When I view the source code with my browser, you can clearly see the FB open graph tags. What I think is causing this is the like button. I "liked" this given prediction via the like button on the page.

The final parameter in the URL is "predictions_post." If the final parameter is set to anything else, PHP sets the og:type to article so that it can be "liked" with the like button. When it's set to "predictions_post", however, it's set to the appropriate object (victory). So, I'm thinking that me liking this prediction might have something to do with this problem of mine. Any ideas?

Comment: In most cases you get this message when FB can't scrape the url. So either the url is wrong or site is protected by htaccess or behind a login.